# Is there a formula to find the exact value of inverse factorials?

Tags: factorial, real-numbers, lambert-w

$x!=y, \space x ∈ ℝ$

Is there a formula to find the exact value of $x$ in this case, assuming that we know the value of $y$?

I could do $L(x)/W(\frac{L(x)}{e}) + \frac{1}{2}$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function and $ L = \ln(\frac{x+c}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$, but that only gives an *approximate* value, and not an exact one.

Comment: [Relevant MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function)

Comment: He uses the same formula as above, but sadly it is only an approximation.

Comment: Practically, you can find the largest prime divisor $p$ of $y$, then check $x=p,p+1,\ldots$.

Comment: I see.

But what if I have really large numbers?

You'd then need a formula, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: ? 

15 char limit gone

Answer (score 1):

In general, the inverse of the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is not known to possess a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) expression, if that is what you're asking. The best you might hope for is an infinite series/product expansion, and/or a continued fraction representation.